# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'QuantizedReluX' with these attrs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting error while running tensorflow 1.8 version on ubuntu(16.04) with the use of conda environment. (python 3.5)

It works with quantized_conv2d and quantized_max_pool, but when I am trying to use quantized_rely_x, it shows me following error :

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'QuantizedReluX' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU,GPU], Registered kernels:

> no registered kernels

It would be great if someone can help me with this.
Is there any possibility to build kernel separately? if yes, please let me know how can I do it with conda environment.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem (I'm using 1.5.1). I'm not sure if quantized operations are supposed to be considered stable, but if they are exported in the public API and included in the documentation they should work! Looking at the source code, there doesn't seem to be any kernel for that operation indeed. I'd say this warrants the creation of a [new issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

Comment: @jdehesa thank you for your quick try. I think I will generate a new issue. By the way if you see inside tensorflow/core/kernels you can see file called quantized_activations.cc that is where the kernels are defined

Comment: Right, that's what I was checking, but while `QuantizedRelu` and `QuantizedRelu6` seem to have defined kernels `QuantizedReluX` appears to be missing (even though the 3 ops are defined together one after another in [`core/ops/nn_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.8.0/tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc)...)